# tfjs codelab 'making predictions from 2D data' use of values keyword in tf-vis.render.scatterplot

Tags: tensorflow.js

Why can't I replace values with another variable name like values1?
values is a js keyword, so I think there is something really fancy going on here.

In this codelab: 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-regression/index.html#2

In this code snippet:

```
async function run() {
  // Load and plot the original input data that we are going to train on.
  const data = await getData();
  const values = data.map(d => ({
    x: d.horsepower,
    y: d.mpg,
  }));

  tfvis.render.scatterplot(
    {name: 'Horsepower v MPG'},
    {values}, 
    {
      xLabel: 'Horsepower',
      yLabel: 'MPG',
      height: 300
    }
  );

  // More code will be added below
}
```

The tfjs documentation doesn't require the use of the values keyword:
https://js.tensorflow.org/api_vis/latest/#render.scatterplot

If I set up the HTML as instructed in the tutorial and use the same js code, I get the expected plot in my browser (firefox).

If I use the following js code, it breaks. Browser remains completely blank, console error message states: TypeError: r is undefined

In the code below, values in both places is changed to values1. That's the only change.

```
async function getData() {
    const dataRequest = await fetch('https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-tutorials/carsData.json');
    const data = await dataRequest.json();
    const cleaned = data.map(car => ({
        mpg: car.Miles_per_Gallon,
        hp: car.Horsepower,
    }))
    .filter(car => (car.mpg != null && car.hp != null));

    return cleaned
}

async function run() {
    // Load and plot the original input data that we are going to train on.
    const data = await getData();
    const values1 = data.map(d => ({
      x: d.hp,
      y: d.mpg,
    }));

    tfvis.render.scatterplot(
      {name: 'Horsepower v MPG'},
      {values1}, 
      {
        xLabel: 'Horsepower',
        yLabel: 'MPG',
        height: 300
      }
    );

    // More code will be added below
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run);
```

I'd expect the above code to result in a plot as with the original code, but I get no plot and a TypeError instead.

Answer (score 0):

`values` is not a js keyword. It is a property of the object `data` that is a parameter of [scatterplot](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_vis/latest/#render.scatterplot). If you want to change the `const values` to `values1`, you have to do the following:

```
tfvis.render.scatterplot(
      {name: 'Horsepower v MPG'},
      {values: values1}, 
      {
        xLabel: 'Horsepower',
        yLabel: 'MPG',
        height: 300
      }
    )
```